# Python - Remove value from array if that value is contained inside other value

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, data-structures

For example:

array = ['123', '1234', '55', '378', '785455'] ====> ['1234', '378', '785455']

my solution to this task is not efficient at all:

```
array = ['123', '1234', '55', '378', '785455', '54314', '4324324', '543535', '54']

def remove_contained(arr):
    to_delete = []
    copy_arr = arr.copy()
    for index, value in enumerate(arr):
        for j_index, j_value in enumerate(arr):
            if value in j_value and value != j_value:
                copy_arr.remove(value)
                break

    return copy_arr
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it ? 
edit: I am looking for a solution that is better than O(n^2 )complexity

Comment: Your code produces `['1234', '378', '785455', '54314', '4324324', '543535']` not `['1234', '378', '785455'] as stated in problem description`.  Which one is the desired result?

Comment: Just gave 2 different examples so it will be more clear.

Comment: Your solution is not O(n^2), it is O(n^3) due to the removal you are doing on `copy_arr`. You can work around that by sorting the array by length, starting from the longest string and then building your result array.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is `append` values to a new `list` instead of copying the old `list` and removing values from it, and also get rid of `enumerate` that doesn't do anything there:

```py
from timeit import timeit


array = ['123', '1234', '55', '378', '785455', '54314', '4324324', '543535', '54']*1000


def remove_contained(arr):
    to_delete = []
    copy_arr = arr.copy()
    for index, value in enumerate(arr):
        for j_index, j_value in enumerate(arr):
            if value in j_value and value != j_value:
                copy_arr.remove(value)
                break

    return copy_arr

def remove_contained_v2(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for value in arr:
        for other_value in arr:
            if value in other_value and value != other_value:
                new_arr.append(value)
    return new_arr
```

Then we time it:

```py
print(timeit("""
remove_contained(array)
""", 'from __main__ import remove_contained, array', number=5
))

print(timeit("""
remove_contained_v2(array)
""", 'from __main__ import remove_contained_v2, array', number=5
))
```

The original takes `21.097198000000002` and the other version `18.412295999999998`. So it's faster.

Comment: The thing is that i am looking for a solution that is better than O(n^2 )complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This could help

Searching in a string created from all elements from the array, except searched key

```
array = ['123', '1234', '55', '378', '785455', '12', '54314', '4324324', '543535', '54']

new_array = []
for idx, elem in enumerate(array):
  x = " ".join(array[0:idx] + array[idx+1:len(array)]) # creating string from array, except current element variable
  if(elem not in x): 
    new_array.append(elem) # if element is not in the string, append it to new array
print(new_array)
```

Comment: I am afraid the output is not correct in your answer. your output is ['1234', '55', '378', '785455', '54314', '4324324', '543535'] instead of ['1234', '378', '785455', '54314', '4324324', '543535']

Comment: Made the corrections. Removed space before element. Now it works

Comment: Its correct now, however my solution is still slightly faster.